# How to disable div or jstree inside div?

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me how to disable a div or elements inside a div?
I have a jstree in my div and I want to disable the div/jstree.

Thanks!

Comment: DO you want to disable every interaction of jstree? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to disable each and every node of jstree.

Comment: Ok, by disable you mean disable click, open, close? Do you know that you can disable jstree nodes programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable click, open, close of jstree node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyvfz/13/)
Basically, it creates a div over your jstree's one so that it is disabled from user interactions.
I guess you can make it visually better, but i think this gives you the idea.
I also checked that there is no strigth way to disable a jstree, even if it could be usefull.
Maybe you'd want to ask the dev in google group...

HTML Code:

```
<button id="disable">Disable</button>
<button id="enable">Enable</button>
<div id="jstree-wrapper">
    <div id="demo" style="height:100px;">
        <ul>
            <li id="node_1_id">
                <a>Root node 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="child_node_1_id">
                     <a>Child node 1</a>
                 </li>
                 <li id="child_node_2_id">
                     <a>Child node 2</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>

     </ul>
     <ul>
                    <li><a>Team A's Projects</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a>Iteration 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>Story A</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story B</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story C</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        <li><a>Iteration 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Story D</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="disabler"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS code:

```
#jstree-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#disabler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}​
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#demo").jstree();

    $("#disable").on("click", function() {
        $("#disabler").css("width", $("#demo").width());
        $("#disabler").css("height", $("#demo").height());
    });

    $("#enable").on("click", function() {
        $("#disabler").css("width", "0px");
        $("#disabler").css("height", "0px");
    });

});
```

Comment: You are welcome, however this is not how stackoverflow works. You should accept the answer (and if you like it upvote too)! Read the faq if you didn't yet!

Comment: Hi andreapier,
I didn't know that. I have accepted your answer now.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good example I didn't find done so simple and good anywhere else. In this example you can simulate the 'disabled' attribute only by adding CSS style as I entered in the code snippet. It disables by using the CSS "visible:hidden", and adds a translucent mask to cover the whole div area and disable anything inside it. You can choose to comment out the 'Visibility:hidden' to be able to see the elements behind the mask, but then they will be tabable, if you don't mind them hidden then uncomment that style.

```js
function disable(elementId, enabling) {

  el = document.getElementById(elementId);


  if (enabling) {
    el.classList.remove("masked");
  } else

  {
    el.classList.add("masked");
  }
}
```

```css
.masked {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: inline-block;
  //visibility:hidden; /* Uncomment this for complete disabling  */
}
.masked::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.2;
  background-color: black;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('Now, click \'OK\' then \'Tab\' key to focus next button.\nThen click \'Enter\' to activate it.');">Test</button>
<div id="div1" style="display:inline-block" class="masked">
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button>
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button><br/>
  <br/>
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button>
  <button onclick="alert('Sample button was clicked.')">Maskakable</button>
</div>
<button>Dummy</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="enableBtn" onclick="disable('div1',true);disable('enableBtn',false);disable('disableBtn',true);">Enable</button>
<button id="disableBtn" onclick="disable('div1',false);disable('enableBtn',true);disable('disableBtn',false);"  class="masked">Disable</button>
```